# Count same values in a row of an ArrayList

Tags: java, jsp, for-loop, if-statement, arraylist

I got an ArrayList which consist of 2 type of values: win & loss. I'm trying to count how many times in a row a win have occurred in the ArrayList. I have noget been able to complete the taske so far.

```
ArrayList <String> wins = new ArrayList<String>();
System.out.print(wins);
//[Won, Won, Won, Loss, Loss, Won, Won, Loss, Loss, Loss, Loss, Loss, Won, Won, Won, Won, Won, Loss]

String value = wins.get(0);

int maxValue=1;
int count = 1 ;

for (int i=1; i<wins.size(); i++){
     if(wins.get(i) == wins.get(i-1)){      
        count++;       
        if(count >= maxValue){
            maxValue = count;
            value = wins.get(i);
        }
    }
}

System.out.println(value + " : " + maxValue );
// Won : 1
```

The outcome is obviusly wrong as win have occurred 4 times in a row at some point in the ArrayList. Can anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: You check each element with the previous, you don't count how many simple won there is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try by using equals and not reference `==` equality:

```
if(wins.get(i) == wins.get(i-1)){
```

Should be:

```
if(wins.get(i).equals(wins.get(i-1))) {
```

Why this could work with String, given that constant are interned, this is not always the case.

Last but not least, you must reset your count when the equality mismatch!

As in:

```
for (int i=1; i<wins.size(); i++){
  String current = wins.get(i);
  if (current.equals(wins.get(i-1))) {      
    count++;       
    if(count >= maxValue){
      maxValue = count;
      value = current;
    }
  } else {
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

Note that you probably don't need `value` at all.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still kinda new but this makes sense. However, I want to ask if you could give me an example of how to reset my counter when I get a mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to rewrite previous code to be an array of booleans, and for some unspecified reason have to be stuck with strings, you can use such construct:

```
for (int i=1; i<wins.size(); i++) {
    if(wins.get(i).equals(wins.get(i-1))) {      
        count++;       
        if(count >= maxValue) {
            maxValue = count;
            value = wins.get(i);
        }
    } else {
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Strings have their own method of comparision. You get answer "1" because your code thinks all those strings are NOT equal.

And as a previous answer states, you have to reset your counter each time you encounter a different element in your row.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. If it is not to much to ask, could you give me an example of how to reset my counter when I encounter a different element? I tried with your modifications above and get the result: "Won : 13" which states the total amounts of wins. So I guess I'm still lagging the reset when another values is encountered.

Comment: ow man! I've misplaced an `else` in the code! The whole construct should be as follows: ```for (int i=1; i<wins.size(); i++) {
     if(wins.get(i).equals(wins.get(i-1))) {      
        count++;       
        if(count >= maxValue) {
            maxValue = count;
            value = wins.get(i);
        }
    }  else {
        count = 0;
    }
}``` -- I've edited my answer for it to be in correct place.

Comment: No worries! But thank you so much. This works perfectly for me. Thank you!